# Enviar objeto de javascript a controlador Java Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring, maven

Cordial saludo. Estoy aprendiendo java realizando un CRUD en SpringBoot, pero quiero enviar los datos por ajax al controlador por medio de un objeto de javascript asi:

```
//Codigo de JS

var cliente = {
    id: 0,
    nombres: "aaaaaa",
    apellidos: "bbbbbb",
    f_nacimiento: "1111",
    cc: "vvvv"
}
```

Y los quiero recibir en el controlador dentro de un objeto de una clase ya definida en java que se llama Clientes con los mismos atributos asi:

```
@RequestMapping("/delete")
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> eliminar2(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok("algo");
}
```

Al probar con postman enviando un json por post con los datos, estos llegan sin problema, pero no me funciona si lo hago utilizando Ajax asi:

```
var data1 = { cliente };

$.ajax({
    url : '/delete',
    data : JSON.stringify(cliente),
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        var CC = 8;
    }
});
```

De la siguiente forma sí me funciona desde el ajax (Sin usar JSON.stringfy) pero enviando los datos separados (No dentro de un objeto), pero hay formularios con mas de diez datos y lo prefiero dentro de un objeto:

```
@PostMapping("/elimin")
public String eliminar1(@NotNull int id, String nombres, String apellidos, String f_nacimiento, String cc) {
    return "redirect:/listar";
}
```

De las formas que no me funcionan me llega un error 415. Mi pregunta es: ¿Como debo formatear ese objeto js para que me llegue al controlador dentro del objeto que este espera como me esta funcionando desde PostMan o de que otra forma se puede hacer pero que sea desde javascript por post?

Comment: ya intentaste con `var data1 = cliente ;`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si, pero igual no funciona. No llega nada y devuelve error 415

Comment: Tip: las comunicciones http no envían un "objeto". Se envían datos serializados usando alguna convención. En resumen, se envían una serie de caracteres que pueden tener un formato, digamos JSON, HTML, Text, etc. Dicho esto, tú debes escoger un formato de datos a enviar desde el cliente y hacer la deserializacion correspondiente en el servidor y viceversa. Pero pretender enviar un POJO sin más (sin un formato práctico) te dará siempre dolores de cabeza. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pero cual es la correcta forma de serializarlos en un JSON? EN el ejemplo utilicé JSON.stringify para convertir el objeto cliente, pero aun asi no llega. Que puede estarme faltando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en ultimas, la forma mas facil que encontré fue convirtiendo el objeto de js a un Json y luego a string y enviarlo por el ajax:

```
var objJavaScript = {
    id: 0,
    nombres: "aaaaaa",
    apellidos: "bbbbbb",
    f_nacimiento: "cccccc",
    cc: "ddddd"
}

cliente = (JSON.stringify(cliente)).toString();

$.ajax({
    url : '/savero3',
    data : { _objJavaScript : objJavaScript },
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        var CC = 8;
    }
});
```

Y luego recibirlo como string en el controlador y convertirlo a objeto de java para poder utilizarlo:

```
@PostMapping("/savero3")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> save3(String _objJavaScript) {

    Cliente objJava = new Gson().fromJson(_objJavaScript , Cliente.class);
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
}
```